# Rewiring an engine

Tags: electrical, ford, wiring, ranger

I have a 1987 Ford Ranger with an LL23 engine in the garage. I've been able to short the starter to the battery and get a compression test done. Mechanically the engine is good. The problem is, somebody got a hold of this vehicle and tore the wiring harness to shreds. What hasn't been cut and spliced haphazardly has been burned away from a short that happened at some point.
My question is, if I have a fuel injected engine with no wiring harness, what would I need to do to get it firing?

I can't find a complete harness anywhere, and while I wouldn't mind making my own, connectors are a problem. I'm not sure where to get replacements and what kinds to get.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! With a fuel injected engine, you're going to need the computer and wiring to make it work. When you say, "tore the wiring harness to shreds" ... what exactly is left?

Comment: I have the computer and what is left of the wiring harness in a box. Most of the wires are left, but they are severely frayed and/or burned. Especially near the connectors. If your familiar with this kind of vehicle, the connectors and wires nearest the master brake cylinder are better than the ones on the right side of the engine bay. I can take pictures.

Comment: I guess I should mention that there are several loose and frayed wires also which I'm not sure how to rewire.

Comment: Your best bet, would be to find a factory wiring diagram for that ECU if it's possible.

Or, Look at the plug that connects to the ECU normally, and compare the wire colors, i.e. if you see Light Green w/ Blue stripe, and theres a Light Green w/ Blue Stripe at the Cylinder 1 Injector trigger, you know that the wire should go there, you can write this all down and create your own wiring diagram, then create a new harness with it. However this may be quite hard. Another option, is to get a standalone ECU (Megasquirt/Haltech/ETC) which come with wiring diagrams and replace the factory ECU.

Comment: @H.Daun will you please provide more information on the "standalone ECU" in an answer please. this is kind of what I'm looking for!

Comment: @Oxymoron, if all you need to do is run the engine, you could look into a standalone ECU, these are a replacement for standard ecu's that come in a car and are normally for upgrading engines performance wise. I have good experience with MegaSquirt which is fully DIY, there are some other great ones that are pre-built (Haltech, LINK Engine Management are some examples.

MegaSquirt is by far the cheapest though.

You can either build and wire it yourself and do the basic tuning yourself, or get a professional to tune the engine for you.

You can find info about these on google.

Comment: @Oxymoron when I say if all you need to do is run the engine, i.e. not controlling ABS or etc, since its an old vehicle it likely only has the engine management side so dont worry about that bit.

Answer (score 1):

If **I** had been handed this "basket case". I'd simply get a (car/truck) manual that has the wiring diagram in it, and patch it back together. I'd also wager that a search for "year model wiring diagram" will turn up some possibly better diagrams that you'll find in the manual.

HTH